# Why nitrogen bond is stronger than carbon bond

Tags: bond

I hear a lot that nitrogen triple bond is the most strong in nature it have 3 empty spaces for 3 new electrons to sit in ,, but carbon have 4 empty space for electrons to sit in isn't this supposed to make stronger 4 bond ?

C-C   Energy 348

C-N.  Energy  308

reference:

science.uwaterloo.ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in your question you aren't necessarily very clear as to what the question is. You are talking about nitrogen triple bonds but have the energy for single bond listed.

The C-N is weaker primarily because of the dipole. The electronegativity of N is 3.04, where as in C it's 2.55. There are forces pushing this apart, and thus leading to a weaker bond strength. Furthermore, the C-C bond is a covalent bond, but the C-N bond acts more like an ionic bond than anything.