# Why is a C-N bond weaker than a C-C?

Tags: bond, energy

As far as I could remember, in the same period, a bond to a more electronegative atom implies in a more polar and stronger bond, due to the greater ionic character. However the bond dissociation energy for the C-X series follows the order: C-F > C-O > C-C > C-N. The same for H-X: H-F > H-O > H-C > H-N.

Why are the bonds to nitrogen weaker than expected? (Or, more speficically, weaker than bonds to carbon, where no dipole is formed)

Values of average bond enthalpies I based my question off:

| Bond | BDE (kJ/mol) |
| --- | --- |
| H-F | 565 |
| C-F | 484 |
| H-O | 463 |
| C-O | 360 |
| H-N | 388 |
| C-N | 305 |
| H-C | 412 |
| C-C | 348 |

Sources: Atkins' Chemical Principles, Housecroft's Inorganic Chemistry, http://butane.chem.uiuc.edu/cyerkes/Chem104ACSpring2009/Genchemref/bondenergies.html

Comment: By the way, I found https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/85767/why-nitrogen-bond-is-stronger-than-carbon-bond but I don't think the answer is satisfactory

Comment: I think it has to do with Nitrogen being half-filled which is a rather stable state.

Comment: Where did you get your BDE data from? The series you've presented have little in common with the values reported in 97th edition of *CRC handbook of chemistry and physics* (p. 9-73):
$$
\begin{array}{lr}
\hline
\ce{A-B} & D^\circ_{298}/\pu{kJ mol^-1} \\
\hline
\ce{C-F} & 513.8 ± 10.0 \\
\ce{C-O} & 1076.63 ± 0.06 \\
\ce{C-C} & 605.03 ± 0.28 \\
\ce{C-N} & 749.31 ± 0.14 \\
\hline
\ce{H-F} & 569.680 ± 0.011 \\
\ce{H-O} & 429.74 ± 0.03 \\
\ce{H-C} & 338.72 ± 0.11 \\
\ce{H-N} & 358.8 ± 0.2 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I'm sorry, but 1000 kJ/mol for a C-O bond is absurd, that may be the value for carbon monoxide. I took a look at Housecroft and Atkins Chemical Principles, and I will update the question with values

Comment: Of course the table is for diatomic molecules. I'm not sure it makes sense to compare average BDEs for random polyatomic species. Not only the values are less accurate, but also the difference in bond energies for the same bond for for various compounds may vary in *hundreds* $\pu{kJ mol^-1}.$ I suggest you either compare series of equivalent polyatomic molecules, or stick with diatomic ones from the table I provided. Otherwise it's no different than comparing average patients' temperatures at the hospitals (persons in the morgue and the ones with fever contributing to theaverage 36ish °C).